# recoverable class Fbd error(s)

Tags: macos, system-administration, osx-server

My server (an XServe xeon 8-core [harpertown arch]) has been spamming kernel warnings lately and I cannot seem to get any concrete information on what may be going wrong.

Has anybody encountered such errors before?

```
Apr  6 13:44:19 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27006 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000200 nerr == 0x00000000 )
Apr  6 13:44:29 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27007 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00100800 )
Apr  6 13:44:54 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27008 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00100800 )
Apr  6 13:44:54 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27009 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00000000 )
Apr  6 13:45:17 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27010 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00000800 )
Apr  6 13:45:24 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27011 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000200 nerr == 0x00000800 )
Apr  6 13:45:31 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27012 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00000800 )
Apr  6 13:45:32 xserve kernel[0]: /!\ WARNING: 27013 recoverable class Fbd error(s) ( ferr = 0x30000800 nerr == 0x00000000 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are ECC errors.  Open Server Monitor and click on the Memory tab; it should tell you which FB-DIMM(s) are bad.

(And yeah, this is not programming-related, shouldn't be on Stack Overflow...)

Answer (score 0):

you should contact your hardware vendor for support.